# Google Chrome on Mac OS X: How to send mailto links to Google Apps Gmail?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, google-chrome, gmail, google-workspace

I was able to get mailto links in Firefox to open up my Google Apps account email, but I can't figure out how to do it in Google Chrome. I have searched for a solution but all the results are outdated and don't seem to work on Mac OS X. How can I set up Google Chrome to send mailto links to my hosted Google Apps email on Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think any number of [these Google Chrome Extensions](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/search?itemlang=&q=open+mailto+links+in+gmail) will work. Remember to restart Google Chrome after installing the extension, or it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Mail Checker Plus](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gffjhibehnempbkeheiccaincokdjbfe) can open mailto-links in your Gmail or Google Apps Mail account

Answer (score 0):

The [Send using Gmail (no button)](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ahldefgplekckalfcolhhnljbbgaiboc) extension provides a cross-platform solution, without the possibly superfluous button taking up space on the top right.